# Copy paste into terminal give '^[' line breaks so code wont run

Tags: python, visual-studio

I have a stupid issue I am struggling to resolve. While testing code in the Terminal panel within Visual Studio I find that the terminal automatically add '^[' as line breaks between my code causing it to fall over.

I can delete these out and then the code runs but obviously i dont want to have to do that every time i am testing something.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
   ...: ^[
   ...: from tqdm import tqdm
   ...: ^[
   ...: import numpy as np
   ...: ^[
   ...: 
   ...: ^[
   ...: from db.sql_connection import connection
   ...: ^[
   ...: from utils.until_funcs import column_strip,
```

Comment: Where are you pasting from? Which shell are you running? What OS are you on?

Comment: I'm just copying from my python script in visual studio, when i paste from here into notebook it doesnt have the brackets. I'm using ipython in the VS terminal and I'm on windows 10 enterprise.

Answer (score 0):

I have no clue what shell your using or what environment this is on, but this happens to me on Win7 so you just have to right click inside the cmd then choose paste